# unset -webkit-scrollbar when in :hover

Tags: html, css

I'm using css that hides the scrollbars until I hover over it (Working on Firefox and IE)

Before the hover it lookes like this:

[image]

```
div#popular-service-container > div:first-child > div::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    /* Safari & Chrome */
    display: none;  
}


div#popular-service-container > div:first-child > div{
    overflow-y: auto; 
    overflow-x: hidden;

    /* IE */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; 
    /* Firefox */
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; 

    height: calc(100% - 160px); 
    margin-top: 20px; 
    padding-bottom: 20px; 
    font-family: KarlaRegular,arial,sans-serif; 
    font-size: .9em; 
    text-align: left; 

    color: #4d4e50; 

}

div#popular-service-container > div:first-child > div:hover{
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar; 
    /* Firefox */
    overflow: scroll; 
}
```

and in IE/Firefox when I mouse over it shows the scrollbars like so:

[image]

But with the code for Chrome hover (The code below shows the options I have tried seperately):

```
div#popular-service-container > div:first-child > div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    /* Safari & Chrome */
    display: initial;   
    display: unset;
}
```

it leaves an empty scrollbar like the example:

[image]

Any ideas on what is missing?

Comment: good reference is here http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve.

```css
div#something {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
div#something:hover {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<div id="something">
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG that made life so much more simple.  I think its because i started with showing when I start scrolling.  But your solution is better.  Thanks for the help