# CSS hover & scroll bug CHROME - the parent element disappear if scrollbar hovered

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover

I have **strange bug** in chrome, while i've tested it in **firefox** and it works fine.

The problem is the hover element that will `display: block` element inside of it, and when there's overflow scroll, if you hover over the scroll the hidden element disappear. While in firefox it's ok.

`Chrome version: 56.0.2924.87`

Reproduce of bug is bellow, **hover over the scrollbar to reproduce it yourself**:

```css
.on_hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.hidden_block {
   display: none;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   left: 0px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.hidden_block .overflow_block {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 160px;
   max-height: 160px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   border: 1px solid blue;
}

/* On hover display hidden block: */
.on_hover:hover .hidden_block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="on_hover">
  Hover me
  <div class="hidden_block">
      <div class="overflow_block">
          <p>Test the content overflow</p>
          <p>Test the content overflow</p>
          <p>Test the content overflow</p>
          <p>Test the content overflow</p>
          <p>Test the content overflow</p>
          <p>Test the content overflow</p>
          <p>Test the content overflow</p>
          <p>Test the content overflow</p>
          <p>Test the content overflow</p>
          <p>Test the content overflow</p>
          <p>Test the content overflow</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Anyone has some solution?**

**Thank you all**

Comment: Wow nice found!

Comment: This seems fine to me. Behaves the same in chrome and firefox.

Comment: @MichaelCoker not for me  Chrome 56.0.2924.87 - Windows10 - what's yours?

Comment: I guess it's bug at our version of Chrome...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan same version but I'm on a mac. Am I doing what's needed to trigger the bug? http://giphy.com/gifs/l3q30PlagK3AebEiY

Comment: Hover the scroll, scroll works too at me

Comment: @MichaelCoker nope. Mousewheel is fine - to reproduce you should hover the scrollbar with your mouse - like you wanted to drag the scrollbars - at that moment the caller looses the `:hover` state which is a definitive bug - The CSS/HTML seems structured perfectly fine, although seems like the scrollbars are painted on another layer that does not registers/keeps the :hover state..... interesting

Comment: @Ultrazz008 ohh gotcha, hover over the _scrollbar_. I thought by "scroll" you meant the scrollable div. Yeah, nice find!

Comment: I've added in answer, the word you said, i am not so good in english.. Sorry...

Comment: I also found another scrollbars bug recently that by using the custom webkit scrollbars makes them disappear from the html-body layer... Removing the custom styles the "classic" scrollbars appeared just fine... (sorry for the longtalk)

Comment: When you said that, this bug can be fixed with `::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
    background: #d8d5d5;
}` it won't disapear on hover at least... :P

Comment: :) but than at some point you'll **eventually** loose it from HTML, BODY ... never found out at what point that happened...

Comment: It happens even using `visibility` (instead of `display`): here's my take: https://jsbin.com/cezumam/2/edit?html,css,output

Comment: It happens on `opacity` `0/1` too.. i've used all three in my project and i just seen it happened when tried to scroll with mouse click..

Comment: I reported the bug.

Comment: Look how funny the bug looks here :D  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40923676/383904 (yes, hover the scrollbars and move your mouse slowly)

Comment: Seems to be no issue in Chromium 59

Comment: I just tested version 57.0.2987.110, and it's not issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It work well on Chrome 55.0.2883.75, Windows 10.
After update to 56.0.2924.87, it's not working.
I guess this is a bug of Chrome version 56, it's necessary to report to Google!